# Datatables add combobox to filter table server-side

Tags: datatable, datatables

I have got a [datatable](https://datatables.net/) using Datatables. I have created and filled the table as shown below. Now I need to implement a combobox to filter all table by years for example , when i select 2012 only records with this date will be shown ..

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="flux-col-1" class="col-md-12">
        <div class="body" id="">
            <div class="row">

                    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>From</th>
                                <th>Object</th>
                                <th>Date</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var ref = $('#example').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "mails",
        "columns": [
                    { "data": "from" },
                    { "data": "object" },
                    { "data": "created" }
                ]
    } );

} );


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) object to pass additional parameters in the request.

This example taken from the documentation:

```
vat oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "data": function ( d ) {
        d.extra_search = $('#myselect :selected').val();
    }
  }
});
```

Say you had a selectlist with `id = 'myselect'`, you would call [draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29) on the selectlist change event:

```
$('#myselect').change(function (e) {
    oTable.draw();
});
```